# Laravel ajax only the first button excute the other button will not response

Tags: ajax, laravel

I need your help guys im stuck because when i click the first button it will execute but the other button it will not excute im using ajax for the form and i use foreach. If someone know how to solve please tell me.

This is my current view code:

```
<tbody>
                    @foreach($customers as $name => $member)
                     @foreach($member->slice(0,1) as $value)
                     <tr>
                         <td>{{$value->id}}</td>
                         <td>{{$value->MATNR}}</td>
                         <td>{{$value->MAKTX}}</td>
                         <td>
                           <select class="form-control">
                              <option>{{$value->UNIT1}}({{$value->CONV1}})</option>
                              <option>{{$value->UNIT2}}({{$value->CONV2}})</option>
                          </select>
                         </td>
                         <td>

                           <select class="form-control">
                            @foreach($member as $value)
                              <option value="{{$value->CHARG}}">{{$value->CHARG}}</option>
                            @endforeach
                          </select>
                         </td>
                         <td>{{$value->VERME}}</td>
                         <td>
                           <form name="ajaxForm" id="ajaxForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">
                            <input type="text" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                            <input type="text" name="id" value="{{$value->id}}"> 
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave" value="add">Save</button>
                         </form>


                         </td>
                    </tr>

                     @endforeach 
                    @endforeach 
                    </tbody>
```

This is my current controller code

```
public function cart() {
    if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
        $id = Request::get('id'); 
            $customers = DB::table('Materials')->select('Materials.MATNR','Materials.MAGRV','Materials.CONV1','Materials.id','Materials.CONV1','Materials.UNIT1','Materials.CONV2','Materials.UNIT2','Materials.MHDHB','Materials.MAKTX','Inventory.CHARG','Inventory.VERME')->join('Inventory',function($join){
                $join->on('Inventory.MATNR','LIKE',DB::raw("CONCAT('%',Materials.MATNR,'%')"));
            })->groupBy('Materials.MATNR','Materials.MAGRV','Materials.CONV1','Materials.id','Materials.CONV1','Materials.UNIT1','Materials.CONV2','Materials.UNIT2','Materials.MHDHB','Materials.MAKTX','Inventory.CHARG','Inventory.VERME')->find($id);

        $cart = ShoppingCart::add($customers->id, $customers->CHARG, 5, 100.00, ['MAKTX' => $customers->MAKTX, 'kg' => $customers->VERME]);

    }   
}
```

And my current route

```
Route::post('/cart', 'system\request_customer@cart');
```

## Ajax current code

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSave").click(function (e) { 
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    })
    e.preventDefault();  
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'cart',
        data: $('#ajaxForm').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            console.log(data);

        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log('Error:', data);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Comment: Please elaborate more clear what your problem is. What do you expect? And what do you get instead? Please review our [SO Question Checklist](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: My problem is to prevent reloading the page after clicking add to cart. And i want use ajax to prevent reloading and i try using ajax but i got always error.

Comment: What did you tried? What error do you get? Add the code to your question and the error too.

Comment: i already solve my problem but there something another problem when i click the add to cart button only first row response but the other button it will not execute

Answer (score 1):

## So this is my new view

```
<form method="POST" class="form-horizontal ajaxForm">
   <input type="hidden" id="token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="{{$value->id}}"> 
   <input type="hidden" name="MATNR" value="{{$value->MATNR}}">
   <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

## and my new ajax

```
$(".ajaxForm").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();    
var formData = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({
    url: 'cart',
    type: 'POST',
    data: formData,
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data)
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I solved it by replacing `id` with `class`. I don't know why this is a solution, but it worked in my case. To make it easier for you, here is what you have to do. Just try it, according to me, It must work!

1. Replace every `#ajaxForm` with `.ajaxForm`.
2. Replace `<form name="ajaxForm" id="ajaxForm" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="">` with `<form name="ajaxForm" class="form-horizontal ajaxForm" novalidate="">`

Let me know if it works. It worked in my case. In my case, I was having the same error. I mean, only first button or submit button worked.

If you are `JQuery` expert or know the reason behind this, please let me know!

Comment: I try what you said but the result is all the column he fetch

Comment: Can you replace `data: $('#ajaxForm').serialize(),` with `data: $(this).serialize(),` and let me know what happens?